# Using weka in C#: Unable to cast object of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`

Tags: c#, java, weka, .net

I am currently working on a project in which I need to use [FP-Growth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning#FP-growth_algorithm) algorithm. I know [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) is a handy tool for it. However, I am using C# for coding (due to some other libraries I need). So, I converted `weka.jar` to `weka.dll` using `IKVM.NET`. Below is a code snippet that i have written:

```
 FPGrowth FPMiner = new FPGrowth();
 FPMiner.buildAssociations(dataset);
 AssociationRules rules = FPMiner.getAssociationRules();
 List<AssociationRule> rule = rules.getRules();
```

This gives me an error as:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'java.util.List' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

So, I added a cast to the last line as:

```
List<AssociationRule> rule = (System.Collections.Generic.List<AssociationRule>)rules.getRules();
```

The error goes away but I get an exception when I run my code, saying:

> System.InvalidCastException was unhandled   Message=Unable to cast
>   object of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to type
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[weka.associations.AssociationRule]'.
>   Source=WindowsFormsApplication1

The stacktrace goes as:

```
  StackTrace:
       at DetectGroup.Form1.GenerateARFF() in C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DetectGroup\DetectGroup\Form1.cs:line 279
       at DetectGroup.Form1.findNearestNeighbours() in C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DetectGroup\DetectGroup\Form1.cs:line 236
       at DetectGroup.Form1.findSelectedTraj() in C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DetectGroup\DetectGroup\Form1.cs:line 165
       at DetectGroup.Form1.button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DetectGroup\DetectGroup\Form1.cs:line 404
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at DetectGroup.Program.Main() in C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DetectGroup\DetectGroup\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:
```

I am unable to figure out what to do now. I have tried searching stuff but haven't yet got the solution. I understand that the error is because `getRules()` returns `java.util.List` while I am trying to use it as `System.Collections.Generic.List`. What can I do to avoid it? Any help would be great!

Also, is there any data mining library (like Weka) available in C#?

Thank you!

Comment: Can't you just iterate over the items in `rules.getRules()` and add those items to a new `List<AssociationRule>`?

Comment: Am afraid I can't. The library doesn't provide an iterator for it!

Comment: You get this error because `getRules` is returning `java.util.List` which is not `System.Collections.Generic.List`

Comment: This link may help to iterate http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-loop-iterate-a-list-in-java/

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes i know that! The question is how can I get rid of it.

Comment: So you've tried writing `foreach (var rule in rules.GetRules())` and that didn't work? If so what was the exception?

Comment: @DanielKelley Yes I did! It gave me an error saying that the AssociationRules does not have a GetEnumerator().

`foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'weka.associations.AssociationRules' because 'weka.associations.AssociationRules' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'`

Comment: @sleekFish you mentioned. "The library doesn't provide an iterator for it!" isnt the type the GetRules() returns an IEnumerable? so you just iterate it.  for(var obj in GetRules()) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: It's weird that one exception states the type is `java.util.ArrayList` and the other states the type is `weka.associations.AssociationRules`. I wish you luck.

Comment: @SecretSquirrel I believe the problem is that `getRules()` is returning `java.util.List` while I am using `C#` which needs a `GetEnumerator()` to use `foreach` loop. Shouldn't the conversion from `jar` to `dll` have handled that!

Comment: @DanielKelley That is because `AssociationRules.getRules()` returns a `java.util.List`. Thank you!

Comment: @sleekFish does the answer by Jon Iles help on this question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708320/converting-values-of-java-util-list-to-string-or-other-normal-format-in-vb

Comment: @SecretSquirrel Yes yes! It did. You don't know you've just saved my day. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question. I used this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9771159/1369241) to solve the problem I was facing. Thanks @SecretSquirrel(see the comments) and @Jon Iles (see the answer I've linked).