# Using StanfordSharpNLP : Unable to cast object of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to type 'edu.stanford.nlp.ling.HasWord'

Tags: c#, stanford-nlp

I'm using Stanford Sharp NLP in my C# project,

I get

System.InvalidCastException was unhandled

Unable to cast object of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to type 'edu.stanford.nlp.ling.HasWord'.

at

```
 foreach (List sentence in new DocumentPreprocessor(clfile))
{
  Tree parse = lp.apply(Arrays.asList(sentence)); //here I get exception  
     ....
    ....
}
```

I'm trying to get pos tag for each word from dependency parser. What I'm messing with. Any clue ?? I tried another question at SO [Using weka in C#: Unable to cast object of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313100/using-weka-in-c-unable-to-cast-object-of-type-java-util-arraylist-to-type-s) , didn't got it or helped me.

Comment: What is the question? The message states that you are treating one type as another, which you can't do (unless there is an implicit conversion between to two). What type does the `lp.apply` method require?

Comment: you are right, Arrays.asList takes object[] a as parameter, changing it to  Tree parse = lp.apply(Arrays.asList(sentence.toArray())); worked

Answer (score 0):

changing it as follow worked, I was passing wrong parameters...

```
 Tree parse = lp.apply(Arrays.asList(sentence.toArray()));
```